# Real Analysis. The Mean Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and differentiable on $(0,1)$.  If $f'(x)\neq 1$ for all $x\in(0,1)$.  Prove there is at most one $c\in[0,1]$ such that $f(c)=c$.

Comment: Put latex between dollars.

Comment: What happens if there are two such numbers?

Comment: @ajotatxe : To call it LaTeX is highly misleading.  It's MathJax.  In LaTeX one does not work only with mathematical notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is another, say $d$, then there exists some $\xi$ such that
$$f'(\xi)=\frac{f(d)-f(c)}{d-c}=\frac{d-c}{d-c}$$

Comment: This notation is just what I was taught in eighth and ninth grades.  Only later did I learn that that "prime" is also used for derivatives.  But I suspect many student in calculus courses would think that by $c'$ you mean the derivative of $c$. ${}\qquad{}$